# R predict() a future table value in a time series

Tags: r, regression, model

I have tree canopy information measured for 5 trees over 4 dates in the following CSV:

```
treeID,X,Y,Z,area,date
1278,888260,936944,58.8,40.7,2021-09-22
1278,888262,936940,53.6,66.3,2021-10-15
1278,888262,936940,53.3,98.0,2021-11-29
1278,888262,936940,53.7,49.3,2021-12-26
1289,888271,936907,20.9,3.8,2021-09-22
1289,888271,936907,20.9,139.8,2021-10-15
1289,888270,936903,23.0,93.9,2021-11-29
1289,888271,936907,21.4,171.8,2021-12-26
1298,888270,936940,27.1,164.4,2021-09-22
1298,888272,936940,25.6,124.3,2021-10-15
1298,888271,936940,26.7,139.4,2021-11-29
1298,888272,936939,25.7,125.7,2021-12-26
1300,888244,937040,23.1,260.1,2021-09-22
1300,888245,937038,23.3,183.3,2021-10-15
1300,888236,937039,23.1,203.9,2021-11-29
1300,888241,937040,64.0,42.6,2021-12-26
1339,888202,937658,55.6,905.1,2021-09-22
1339,888201,937658,55.9,123.3,2021-10-15
1339,888202,937657,55.8,772.9,2021-11-29
1339,888202,937657,55.8,794.4,2021-12-26
```

I have the following R code:

```
# Load libraries and packages

# packages list and library function
packages <- c("rgdal",
              "rgeos",
              "sf",
              "tidyverse",
              "sp",
              "rgl",
              "ggplot2",
              "gstat")
lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE, quietly = T)

tpdbo <- read.csv("E:/CWJ/outs/ttdata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = " ")

# generate regression forecast
tree.list <- unique(tpdbo$treeID)
RAf <- NULL
newDate <- as.Date("2022-06-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

for(tree in tree.list) {
  treRAf <- tpdbo[tpdbo$treeID == tree, ]
  fit <- with(treRAf, lm(treRAf$convhull_area~treRAf$date))
  prediction <- predict(fit, newDate)
  corcoef <- cor(treRAf$convhull_area, data.frame(as.numeric(treRAf$date)))
  RAf <- append(RAf, tree,)
  RAf <- append(RAf, prediction[4],)
  RAf <- append(RAf, newDate,)
  RAf <- append(RAf, corcoef)
}

tree.forecast <- matrix(data = RAf, nrow = length(tree.list),
                        ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(tree.forecast) <- c("treeID", "area", "date", "corcoef")
tree.forecast.df <- as.data.frame(tree.forecast)
tree.forecast.df <- na.omit(tree.forecast.df)
tree.forecast.df$date <- as.Date("2022-06-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

My intent is to predict the area for each treeID on 2022-06-01 using:

```
prediction <- predict(fit, newDate)
```

but it gives me this:

```
> prediction
      1       2       3       4 
905.081 123.319 772.911 794.367
```

and the correlation coefficient is NA:

```
> cor(treRAf$convhull_area, data.frame(as.numeric(treRAf$date)))
     as.numeric.treRAf.date.
[1,]                      NA
Warning message:
In data.frame(as.numeric(treRAf$date)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

And my output is empty, which makes no sense to me as this code at least provided a list of values in previous versions.

I'm at the far edge of my skillset already so I'm at a loss where to look for a solution.

Comment: Maybe this is not quite the right substack. Even though your data holds X/Y-Values your question is about something purely different.

Comment: Yes, my question is about forecasting the "area" based on a linear regression model. The X/Y is incidental to this and not processed in this routine. I have 4 measurements of area for each tree in time series and I want to forecast the area at a future time. This is a subset of over 10k trees that I exported as a CSV just to share some sample data with the blog. The output is a data frame that will become a SpatialPointsDataFrame eventually. The important values are the forecasted areas of each tree.